# can't send data to pho file in Xcode

Tags: php, xcode

I'm trying to send data to an online database using Xcode, php and mysql

The mysql database and PHP file are created and tested OK.

But my IOS code does not send the string to the PHP file... there is no error, it simple does nothing!

Anyone here know what could be wrong?

Here is the iOS code:

```
- (IBAction)send:(id)sender {

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"nome=%@", nome.text];
const char *urlUTF8 = [post UTF8String];
NSString *postBody = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:urlUTF8];

NSData *postData = [postBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSString *postDataLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myURLgoes.here/myPHPfile.php"]]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postDataLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

and this is the PHP file:

```
<?php
  $con=mysqli_connect("MYSITE.COM","USER","PASSWORD","DATABASE");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
 echo '{"query_result":"ERROR"}';
}

$nome = $_GET['nome'];


$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user (nome) 
          VALUES ('$nome')");

if($result == true) {
    echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: I haven't used IOS/xcode before but `[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]` seems like it'd be sending over `POST`, not `GET`. Do you get empty records or no records? If you monitor your access logs does the IOS request make to to your PHP script?

Comment: I get no records... and the logs says nothing... it is like the IOS code is doing nothing at all...

Comment: Error log or access log? If the access log shows nothing then your IOS code is not sending. If that is the case the PHP is irrelevant and should be removed. The simpler the question is the easier it will be for users to answer.

Comment: I get no errors at all, it is like the IOS code is not sending the data to the PHP file on the server.

Comment: this has nothing to do with PHP or mysql. test your ios code in isolation.

Comment: a `NSMutableRequest` is just a request object, it does not initiate an http connection. Is is used as input to an `NSURLConnection` object for example... other Frameworks/Classes can provide the http transport control logic.

Comment: Thanks YvesLeBorg! with your help I managed to make the communication between the iOS app and the PHP file. But now I have another problem: The MySQL database is being reached but NO DATA is written... only the ID field (auto increment) is shown... none other... how can I post my updated code here for you to see?